# Android: Different fragment for each ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

In Android, when creating Action Bar Tabs with ViewPager, what's a way of giving different fragment for each ViewPager? Let's say I want the first tab to be login form, the second a signup, in fragment_login.xml and fragment_signup.xml files respectively.

Where/how do I initialize these fragments and show as appropriate tabs are selected? I would prefer to do this all in one Fragment class, instead of creating individually for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a small number of fragments then you can implement [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html). For showing larger number of fragments [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) is recommended. You can keep all the fragments in one class(Activity class) and make each fragment a subclass of that class but I think having different classes in respective .java files would make your code more elegant. 
Initializing the fragment is generally done during fragmentTransaction and appropriate data are passed via Bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I will give it a try and create different classes for each fragment in ViewPager.